# Identifying bridged ad-hoc connection from router

Tags: network, wifi

assuming I can access router only. There is a machine#1 connected directly to the router through LAN and it hosts separate ad-hoc wifi. Now machine#2 using bridged connection connects to router through machine#1 using mentioned ad-hoc. With access only to router can I detect machine#2 or not? According to my knowledge router only displays MAC of machine#1 but I might be wrong.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the use of TCP/IP networking, yes you can. It will list the IP address (and MAC) in the ARP table.

Depending on the configuration of your network, that IP address may be from a different range than the ones your routers DHCP server gives out.

Comment: No, it will not. If machine#1 is using NAT, only its IP or MAC will ever show up.

Comment: NAT not relevant here as everything is happening on the LAN & the WiFi is bridged.